# I'm trying to get user input using Scanner but i got an error

Tags: java

I got this error while I'm coding but I can't solve it
please enter the length of the rectangle

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`
`at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)`
`at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)`
`at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)`
`at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)`
`at lab3.main(lab3.java:19)`

i'm trying to get the user input for the length and width and this my code

```
import java.util.*;  
public class lab3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      
//input section,using assignment stats
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // creates an instance of the 

int length;
int width; 
int area = 0;


System.out.println("please enter the length of the rectangle");
    length = input.nextInt(); 
System.out.println("please enter the width of the rectangle");
    width = input.nextInt(); 

//process section 

area = length * width;

// output section 

System.out.println("Length = "+ length);
System.out.println("Width = "+ width);
System.out.println("Area = Length * Width= "+ area);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you enter anything?

Comment: when I execute it shows this result   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212) at lab3.main(lab3.java:19)

Comment: I can't see anything obvious in your code that would cause a `NoSuchElementException`. Is this the exact code that is causing the error? A [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) is `thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist`, however, you don't have any such methods in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown us all your code, but the issue is most likely that you have a larger project with multiple scanners.

If you ever create a scanner to `System.in` like so `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` you must never close it with `input.close();` because this will close the `System.in` stream, and will cause all future scanners created using `System.in` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

The simple solution is just to never close a `System.in` scanner, or have a single `System.in` scanner that is shared between all classes and methods that need to use it.

This will throw a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
Scanner firstScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a value");
int firstInput = firstScanner.nextInt();
firstScanner.close(); //this line is the problem

Scanner secondScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a value");
int secondInput = secondScanner.nextInt();
```

This code will work as expected by removing `close()`:

```
Scanner firstScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a value");
int firstInput = firstScanner.nextInt();
//firstScanner.close(); //Remove this line

Scanner secondScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a value");
int secondInput = secondScanner.nextInt();
```